# How to use a function argument as npy method, if possible

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-random

I am trying to create a function that will take a numpy dstr name as an argument and plot a histogram of random data points from that distribution.

if it only works on npy distributions that require 1 argument that is okay.  Just really stuck trying to create the np.random.distribution()...
\

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

#Define a function (Fnc) that produces random numpy distributions (dstr)
#Fnc args: [npy dstr name as lst of str], [num of data pts]
def get_rand_dstr(dstr_name):
  npdstr = dstr_name
  dstr = np.random.npdstr(user.input("How many datapoints?"))
  #here pass each dstr from dstr_name through for loop
  #for loop will prompt user for required args of dstr (nbr of desired datapoints)
  return plt.hist(df)

get_rand_dstr('chisquare')
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just have your function take `np.random.chisquare` as an argument instead of a `'chisquare'` string?

Comment: @user2357112-supports-monica  Other than it didn't come to mind (lol)...  I'm new to statistics so I was hoping to write a function that would allow me to quickly visualize/compare different distributions.  I'm also new to python so I wanted it as close to plain text as possible.  

But I'm going to give it a try because that seems like a great straight forward solution.  thank you for your input!  I'll comment how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

**The accepted answer is incorrect and does not work.** The problem is that [NumPy's random distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/routines.random.html#distributions) take different required arguments, so it's a little fiddly to pass `size` to all of them because it's a kwarg. (That's why the example in the accepted solution returns the wrong number of samples — only 1, not the 5 that were requested. That's because the first argument for `chisquare` is `df`, not `size`.)

It's common to want to invoke functions by name. As well as not working, the accepted answer uses `eval()` which is a common suggested solution to the issue. But it's generally accepted to be a bad idea, [for various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

A better way to achieve what you want is to define a dictionary that maps strings representing the names of functions to the functions themselves. For example:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DISTRIBUTIONS = {
    'standard_cauchy': np.random.standard_cauchy,
    'standard_exponential': np.random.standard_exponential,
    'standard_normal': np.random.standard_normal,
    'chisquare': lambda size: np.random.chisquare(df=1, size=size),
}

def get_rand_dstr(dstr_name):
    npdstr = DISTRIBUTIONS[dstr_name]
    size = int(input("How many datapoints?"))
    dstr = npdstr(size=size)
    return plt.hist(dstr)

get_rand_dstr('chisquare')
```

This works fine — for the functions I made keys for. You could make more — there are 35 I think — but the problem is that they don't all have the same API. In other words, you can't call them all just with `size` as an argument. For example, `np.random.chisquare()` requires the parameter `df` or 'degrees of freedom'. Other functions require other things. You *could* make assumptions about those things and wrap all of the function calls (like I did, above, for `chisquare`)... if that's what you want to do?

Comment: yes, this is the most workable code. The way of organizing different distributions in a single dictionary is really appreciating. good work boss, i learned how to organize a code in fruitful though i know the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, it might be helped you[image: below image shows the value and plot]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

def get_rand_dstr(dstr_name):
#     npdstr = dstr_name  
    dstr = 'np.random.{}({})'.format(dstr_name, (input("How many datapoints?"))) # for using any distribution need to manipulate here 
                                                                                 # cause number of args are diffrent for diffrent distibutions           
    print(dstr)
    df = eval(dstr)
    print(df)
#     dstr1 = np.random.chisquare(int(input("How many datapoints?")))
#     print(dstr1)
    return plt.hist(df)

# get_rand_dstr('geometric')  
get_rand_dstr('chisquare')
```

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

OMG it works like a DREAM.  You are my hero, and probably several of my classmates heroes as well.  Thank you!

Comment: No, I'm afraid this does not work at all. The first argument for `chisquare` is `df`, not `size`. I explained this in my answer. So in the example shown here, you are not getting a distribution, you are getting a single data point from the distribution with `df=1`. It's also considered a bad idea to use `eval()` at all, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice.

Comment: @Candy This solution does not work. I updated my answer to explain more about it.